# Size increases when csv is imported to mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I imported a csv into MongoDB using Compass. The csv file has a size of 755 MB, but in Mongo, the collection shows a size of 2.8 GB? Why is this?
Also, the csv has a lot of sprasely populated fields. In Mongo, these fields are set to empty strings for most of the rows(documents). Is there a option to say only create the field for a particular document if the value is not missing.

Comment: What version of Compass are you using and what is the label on the column where you are checking the size? When you click to view a database in Compass 1.16, the list of collections shows "Total Document Size" which is the size of the uncompressed data, not the size of the files on disk. The data size will be larger than the original CSV because each MongoDB document includes the field names, however the size on disk is generally much smaller after compression.

Comment: CSV import in Compass favours convenience over control. For finer control I suggest using the MongoDB server command line tool [`mongoimport`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) which has conversion options like [`--ignoreBlanks`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption-mongoimport-ignoreblanks), [`--columnsHaveTypes`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption-mongoimport-columnshavetypes), and [`--mode`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption-mongoimport-mode).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loading a sparse file can unnecessarily eat up a lot of space.   Consider 14,493,120 rows of this line:

```
foo,bar,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,zip
```

The file size is 797,229,120 bytes.  So let's go ahead and load it with mongoimport with NO `--ignoreBlanks`. On the MacBook, this takes 8m45s to load and produces an avg size doc of 490 bytes for a total of 7,101,710,784 *uncompressed* bytes.  The WiredTiger storage engine will achieve a 6.8x compression on this to yield an on-disk rep of only 1,044,369,232 bytes and the _id index of 145,854,464 bytes.  Call it 1200MB total.  OK, somewhat bigger than the input 797MB flatfile.

Load it with `--ignoreBlanks` and the landscape changes.  It takes only 5m55s to load and produces an avg size doc of 63 bytes -- about 7.7x smaller.  The total uncompressed size is 72,758,890 bytes, also about 7.7x smaller.  The compression ratio is down to 3.2x but this still yields an on-disk rep of 286,487,020 bytes.  Not surprisingly, the _id index is the same size (145MB) but 286MB + 145MB ~= 432MB.  Compared to 797MB of raw CSV, the point should be clear:  Loading sparse files into MongoDB with `--ignoreBlanks` yields a significantly smaller footprint; in this case, **close to 2x smaller on-disk including indexes than the raw CSV files**